# How to replace arrays in file using bash?

Tags: arrays, shell, replace, command-line-interface, io-redirection

I have a file like this:

```sh
# [...]

ver=1.0
source_x86_64=("file-$ver.tar.gz" "file-$ver.tar.gz.sig")
source_i386=("file-$ver.tar.gz")
sha256sums_x86_64=("54842def55267131a12494cd6d23243df1fa3eee60dd418f0a84737f1feafc28"
                   "SKIP")
sha256sums_i386=("c453479cbada5139cc3f494f9e72f192451780c7d936d7aa15be99c48deb4237")

# [...]
```

I need to update the hashes each time a new version is released. I can run a program that downloads the three files and generates the sha256sum for each of them:

For instance `makepkg -gA` with "ver=1.1" outputs

```sh
sha256sums_x86_64=('82cfaef1f73748a0f814dd06eee3af1fd34232d6dc49421a13176255fed24845'
                   'SKIP')
sha256sums_i386=('7324bed84c99eb51aa7d639d7c087154291f27e9f494f3cc9315adabc974354c')
```

How I can overwrite the arrays in the original file, possibly keeping the same position, without appending the program output to the end and deleting the original arrays?

Note that the first array spans multiple lines and that arrays in the file may differ in size from the ones in the program output (e.g. if a file has been added to the source array and the hash array in the file has not been updated accordingly).

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Makepkg#Generate_new_checksums https://github.com/alexchamberlain/pacman/blob/master/contrib/updpkgsums.sh.in#L79

Comment: @KamilCuk I was searching for a way to make that awk code more portable and applicable to other cases where the old array has the same name of the old one, like `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` arrays if you have to add an element

Comment: `I was searching for a way to make that awk code more portable` It's very portable, any POSIX awk I think should work `applicable to other cases` Then modify the regex `[[:blank:]]*(md|sha)[[:digit:]]+sums=/,/\)[[:blank:]]*(#.*)?$` with your own one. `like /etc/mkinitcpio.conf arrays if you have to add an element` Stateful modifying files is a nightmare and can lead to a bunch of mistakes. Consider instead `ansible` or `chef` or `puppet` and consider just provisioning the whole file from a template instead of modifying it. Managing state is hard.

Comment: If you want to modify files, instead use a full-blown parser, instead of workarounds like `awk` pasring file line by line. Simplest is sourcing the file in bash and outputting (or appending) new file with `declare -p`.